# Updating data via stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables (Table 1 and Table 2) which are listed below. I wanted to update a column in Table 2 while getting the data from Table 1.

Table 1

```
+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
+  form_id  +   request_id  +         BatchNo     +
+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
+  5649464  +      562      +     Batch5649464_1  +
+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
+  5649464  +      563      +     Batch5649464_11 +
+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Table 2

```
+------------+---------------+-----------+
+  NumberId  +   ServiceName +    RefId  +
+------------+---------------+-----------+
+  5649464   +      XYZ      +     0     +
+------------+---------------+-----------+
+  5649464   +      XYZ      +     0     +
+------------+---------------+-----------+
```

In Table 1 there are two rows as per list above. By Default my RefId is 0. I have to update that column with the data from Table 1 (request_id). As you can see request_id have two different data. Both data (562 and 563) should get updated as per my Expected Output. But right now I am getting result as per my Initial Output. **Can anyone help to get as per my Expected Output?**

```
DECLARE @Tempnumbers TABLE
            (
              form_id INT ,
              request_id INT
            );

         ;
        WITH    Result
                  AS ( SELECT   form_id ,
                                CONVERT(BIGINT, ( CONVERT(VARCHAR, request_id) )) AS request_id
                       FROM     [Table1] 
                     )
            INSERT  INTO @Tempnumbers
                    SELECT  form_id, request_id
                    FROM    Result;

        UPDATE  DT
        SET    RefID = request_id
       FROM    Table2 DT 
       INNER JOIN @Tempnumbers TN ON TN.NumberId = DT.form_id;
```

Initial Output

```
+------------+---------------+-----------+
+  NumberId  +   ServiceName +    RefId  +
+------------+---------------+-----------+
+  5649464   +      XYZ      +     562   +
+------------+---------------+-----------+
+  5649464   +      XYZ      +     562   +
+------------+---------------+-----------+
```

Expected Output

```
+------------+---------------+-----------+
+  NumberId  +   ServiceName +    RefId  +
+------------+---------------+-----------+
+  5649464   +      XYZ      +     562   +
+------------+---------------+-----------+
+  5649464   +      XYZ      +     563   +
+------------+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: How you decided for second +  5649464   +      XYZ      + is 563? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: There is no logic. Its just a ReferenceId which I have to add it in Table2. If you want to add 563 in first row and 562 in second, I don't have any issue with that as well. As long as both data from request_id  from Table 1 is updated to Table 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to join tables and update `RefId`

```
;WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY form_id ORDER BY request_id) as rn
    FROM Table1 t1
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NumberId ORDER BY RefId) as rn
    FROM Table2 t2
)

UPDATE c2
SET RefId = c1.request_id
FROM cte1 c1
INNER JOIN cte2 c2
    ON c1.form_id = c2.NumberId AND c1.rn = c2.rn
```

If you then select from `Table2` you will get:

```
NumberId    ServiceName RefId
5649464     XYZ         562
5649464     XYZ         563
```

Answer (score -1):

Table2 has no primary key, so you can't update first row with one value and second row with different value, unless you add primary key to table2